# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity - Read data from http response timeout

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I use the Copy activity to query an HTTP endpoint, but after 5 minutes I keep getting the following error "Read data from response timeout":
Error Code: ErrorCode=UserErrorReadHttpDataTimeout,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Read data from http response timeout. If this is not binary copy, you are suggested to enable staged copy to accelerate reading data, otherwise please retry.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The operation has timed out.,Source=System,'"

[image: Timeout Read Response Data]

[image]

The request runs in full length without interruption on the server side (visible in the logs)
[image: Server Logs]
I searched online and I only found this:

[image]

[image]
The error gets triggered as soon as Reading from source hits 5 Minutes

PS: The error seems to be happening only on certain endpoints (same server but different endpoint, I don't get any timeout error)
[image]

Have any of you ever had a problem like this? If so, how did you solve it?
Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 0):

> Error Message - Read data from http response timeout. If this is not
> binary copy, you are suggested to enable staged copy to accelerate
> reading data, otherwise please retry.

As mentioned in the above error message, you need to try  staged copy.

Also you need to configure Retry settings.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/51055/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-retry.html

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work :/